# cron does not write in the file

Tags: bash, cron

I just start with cron jobs and I wanted to start with an easy task.
Create a file in my home folder with the output of the `ifconfig`.
So I created `test.sh`, which I made it executable with the:

```
#!/bin/bash          
ifconfig > /home/myname/ipt
```

inside. When I run it from terminal it creates the file `ipt` which has the output `ifconfig`.

To add the script in my `crontab` I entered:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and I added my script like this:

```
* * * * * /home/myname/test.sh
```

and the first minute it creates the file ipt which has an lock icon which is for read only and inside is empty.

There are two questions:

1st Why it is empty?

2nd Why it is read only file?

Comment: Use the full path to `ifconfig` i.e. `/sbin/ifconfig >/home/myname/ipt`

Comment: Please pay attention to the [format of `/etc/crontab`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man5/crontab.5.html)! You seem to be missing the column with the name of the user, under which the command shall be run. I'm surprised the editor `crontab -e` accepted your changes despite the illegal syntax.

Comment: @DavidFoerster you don't need the name of the user in user's own crontab i.e. `crontab -e` ....you need user's name in the generic ones i.e. `/etc/crontab`, `/etc/cron.d/*`

Comment: Also, you should use a `>>` as opposed to a `>` if you want to include previous entries, as `>` will delete whatever is currently there before writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try what @heemayl said, use full path within your `test.sh`:

```
/sbin/ifconfig >/home/myname/ipt
```

### Explanation

On command prompt and running scripts, you are doing so as your user which has certain capabilities, such as

- having $PATH variable include `/sbin/` to be able to "know" whenever asking for `ifconfig` refers to `/sbin/ifconfig`

Cron however is not the same exact user as you

- thus when cron tries to run, it doesn't know where `ifconfig` is
- unless of course, you specify exactly where: `/sbin/ifconfig`

The effect of not knowing where a program is, you can test for yourself, try running a program that does not exist on your command prompt:

```
$ doesnotexist > ipt2
bash: doesnotexist: command not found
```

Notice when you:

```
$ ls -lh ipt2
-rw-r--r-- 1 youruser youruser 0 Dec 17 14:48 ipt2
```

It is a

- 0 byte file
- read-only

This is exactly the same result you originally found with crontab, where it did not know what `ifconfig` is, resulting in making a 0 byte, mostly read-only file.

So in cron, help it find the program by just giving it the full path, and as long as you have no permission issues, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer no 1:**

The file was empty because I didn't give the full name of the command thanks to @heemayl  and @user454038

**Answer no 2:**

The file was read only because I created a cronjob as root
and I was trying to open it as user

```
sudo crontab -e
```

but I just had to created as user without sudo

```
crontab -e
```

So working like user the `.sh` file would be

```
/sbin/ifconfig > ipt
```

and the crontab

```
* * * * * $HOME/test.sh
```

and I use the variable `$HOME` for my user again.

So this creates the file that I wanted without wrong permissions.

Thank you all for your help.